# Probability and Uniform distribution lottery question

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose that a person has a lottery ticket from which she will win $X$ dollars, where $X \sim\mathrm{ Unif} (0,4)$. Suppose her utility function is $U(x) = x\alpha$ for $x \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise, where $\alpha > 0$ is some fixed constant. For how many dollars is she willing to sell the ticket (i.e., what is $E[U(X)]$)?

I am little confused how to start this problem?

Is it going to be $\int_0^1 x*\alpha dx$?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^4 x dx = 2$$

Comment: Isn´t $\alpha$ an exponent ? $U(x) = x^α$

Comment: You are close. Her expected utility is $\int_0^4 \left(x^\alpha\cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)\,dx$.  Here I am assuming that you meant to write $x^\alpha$ for the utility and not $x\alpha$. If you meant $x\alpha$, the modification should be clear.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Your answer does not answer my question straightforward. What do you think is $U(x)$ ?

Comment: If the utility function is $x^\alpha$, I wrote down the integral for calculating $E(U(X))$, exactly what is being asked, apart from the integral evaluation. When we calculate the integral, we get after a while $\frac{4^{\alpha}}{\alpha+1}$.